# Rails validate form_for before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to validate that all the necessary fields have been completed in my form_for before it submits, and am 95% there but it still submits before checking and throwing an alert.

Here's the beginning of the form:

```
<%= form_for Product.new, :options => {:id => "new_listing", :onSubmit => "validateForm()"}, :url => {:action => "create"}, :html => {:multipart => true}, :builder => Judge::FormBuilder do |f| %>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
<script>
  validateForm = function(){
    judge.validate(document.getElementById('name_input'), {
        valid: function(element) {
          element.style.border = '1px solid green';
        },
        invalid: function(element, messages) {
          element.style.border = '1px solid red';
          alert(messages.join(','));
        }
      }); 
  };

</script>
```

What do I need to do now to make sure that an alert is thrown when the name_input field hasn't been filled out BEFORE it submits to the backend? Something to do with booleans but I'm not an expert here.

Comment: Why are you following these routes of avoiding Rails to do the validations, and using jQuery?  With the given information it is difficult to debug the issue.  What is `judge` in your script block?  Where is the script block placed? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning false when the validations are invalid. When you use a `onSubmit` javascript function, it will continue doing whatever is next unless the js returns false.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking for help on *how* to write the code for this.

Comment: so, you will want your javascript to be something like: `if(document.getElementById('name_input').text()=="") { return false; } else { return true; }` and you can make any alert you want before the returns.

Answer (score 0):

Its a blind guess here, but this has chances to work:

```
judge.validate(document.getElementById('name_input'), {
    ...,
    invalid: function(element, messages) {
      ...
      return false;
    }
});
```